Ktor, serialization in StatusPages not working
Here is code from Auth guard:
  val sessionToken = call.request.cookies.get("session_token")
  if (sessionToken == null) throw HttpException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized", "User is not authorized, please login")


  val sessionRaw = _redis.get("session:$sessionToken")
  if (sessionRaw == null) throw HttpException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized", "User is not authorized, please login again")


  val _session = Json.decodeFromString<Session>(sessionRaw)
  val user = _userCollection.find( Document("uid", _session.uid) ).firstOrNull()
  if (user == null) throw HttpException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized", "User is not authorized, please login again")

  // if ok
  return user.uid


HttpException:
class HttpException (
  val statusCode: HttpStatusCode,
  val errorType: String,
  val errorDetail: String,

  ) : Exception("HttpException")

In App.kt :
  install(ContentNegotiation) { json() }
  .....
  @Serializable
  data class ErrResponseBody (val errorType: String, val errorDetail: String)

  install(StatusPages) {
    exception<Throwable> { call, cause ->
      when(cause) {

        // http error
        is HttpException -> {
          val responseBody = ErrResponseBody(cause.errorType, cause.errorDetail)
          println(responseBody)
     
          //call.respond(cause.statusCode, "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA") // this one work for some reason!
          call.respond(cause.statusCode, responseBody)
        }

        // 500
        else -> {
          val responseBody = ErrResponseBody("Internal server error", "")
          call.respond(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, responseBody)
        }

      }
    }
  }

I've made sure execution happens till error handler
So, here is the problem:
Serialization there not works, and call.response(T) not works
With returning ErrResponseBody (serialization required)
enter image description here
Without (with "AAAAAAAAA" instead of T)
enter image description here
Edit:
in router
fun Routing.userRouting() {

    ...
    /* ROUTE */
    route("/get-dir-contents") {

      // models
      @Serializable
      data class RequestBody (
        val where: String,
      )
      @Serializable
      data class ResponseBody (
        val contents: List<FsEntity>,
      )

      // handler
      post {
        val uid = AuthGuard(call) // AUTH NEEDED // <---- HttpException occurs here =)

        val body = call.receiveValid<RequestBody>()
        val whereEid = GetValidEid(body.where)

        val contents = FsEntityService.getDirContents(
          where = body.where,
          _whereEid = whereEid,
          uid = uid
        )

        // if ok
        val responseBody = ResponseBody(contents)
        call.respond(responseBody)
      }
    }
    ...
}

Edit:
2024-08-16 08:56:00.566 [eventLoopGroupProxy-7-1] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing -- Trace for [api, user-service, login]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /api, segment:1 -> SUCCESS @ /api
    /api/user-service, segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /api/user-service
      /api/user-service/create-new-user, segment:2 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /api/user-service/create-new-user
      /api/user-service/login, segment:3 -> SUCCESS @ /api/user-service/login
        /api/user-service/login/(method:POST), segment:3 -> SUCCESS @ /api/user-service/login/(method:POST)
      /api/user-service/refresh-session, segment:2 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /api/user-service/refresh-session
      /api/user-service/get-current-user, segment:2 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /api/user-service/get-current-user
      /api/user-service/get-user-image, segment:2 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /api/user-service/get-user-image
    /api/fs-service, segment:1 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /api/fs-service
    /api/share-service, segment:1 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /api/share-service
    /api/openapi.yaml, segment:1 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /api/openapi.yaml
    /api/redoc, segment:1 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /api/redoc
    /api/rapidoc, segment:1 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /api/rapidoc
    /api/other-service, segment:1 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /api/other-service
  /share, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /share
  /download-service, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /download-service
Matched routes:
  "" -> "api" -> "user-service" -> "login" -> "(method:POST)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS @ /api/user-service/login/(method:POST)
2024-08-16 08:56:00.577 [eventLoopGroupProxy-7-1] TRACE i.k.server.engine.DefaultTransform -- No Default Transformations found for class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel and expected type TypeInfo(type=class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteReadChannel, reifiedType=interface io.ktor.utils.io.ByteReadChannel, kotlinType=io.ktor.utils.io.ByteReadChannel) for call /api/user-service/login
2024-08-16 08:56:00.578 [eventLoopGroupProxy-7-1] TRACE i.k.s.p.c.ContentNegotiation -- Skipping for request type class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteReadChannel because the type is ignored.
2024-08-16 08:56:00.644 [eventLoopGroupProxy-7-1] TRACE org.mongodb.driver.cluster -- Asynchronously selecting server with selector ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}
2024-08-16 08:56:00.646 [eventLoopGroupProxy-7-1] TRACE org.mongodb.driver.cluster -- Asynchronously selected server localhost:27017
2024-08-16 08:56:00.647 [eventLoopGroupProxy-7-1] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection -- Checkout started for connection to localhost:27017
2024-08-16 08:56:00.650 [AsyncGetter-3-thread-1] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection -- Connection created: address=localhost:27017, driver-generated ID=3
2024-08-16 08:56:00.661 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection -- Connection ready: address=localhost:27017, driver-generated ID=3
2024-08-16 08:56:00.662 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection -- Connection checked out: address=localhost:27017, driver-generated ID=3
2024-08-16 08:56:00.676 [Thread-3] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command -- Command "find" started on database TinyCloud using a connection with driver-generated ID 3 and server-generated ID 65 to localhost:27017. The request ID is 6 and the operation ID is 4. Command: {"find": "users", "filter": {"email": "string"}, "batchSize": 64, "$db": "TinyCloud", "lsid": {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "UFv4ZZGUSVC4Cb1oF8XdhA==", "subType": "04"}}}}
2024-08-16 08:56:00.682 [Thread-4] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command -- Command "find" succeeded in 6.194838 ms using a connection with driver-generated ID 3 and server-generated ID 65 to localhost:27017. The request ID is 6 and the operation ID is 4. Command reply: {"cursor": {"firstBatch": [], "id": 0, "ns": "TinyCloud.users"}, "ok": 1.0}
2024-08-16 08:56:00.685 [Thread-4] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.operation -- Received batch of 0 documents with cursorId 0 from server localhost:27017
2024-08-16 08:56:00.685 [Thread-4] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection -- Connection checked in: address=localhost:27017, driver-generated ID=3
2024-08-16 08:56:00.696 [eventLoopGroupProxy-7-1] TRACE i.k.s.p.statuspages.StatusPages -- Call /api/user-service/login failed with cause _4Tipsy.TinyCloudAPI.exceptions.HttpException: HttpException
2024-08-16 08:56:00.705 [eventLoopGroupProxy-7-1] TRACE i.k.s.p.statuspages.StatusPages -- Executing (io.ktor.server.application.ApplicationCall, kotlin.Throwable) -> kotlin.Unit for exception _4Tipsy.TinyCloudAPI.exceptions.HttpException: HttpException for call /api/user-service/login
2024-08-16 08:56:00.712 [eventLoopGroupProxy-7-1] TRACE i.k.s.p.c.ContentNegotiation -- No suitable content converter found for response type class _4Tipsy.TinyCloudAPI.AppKt$mainModule$ErrResponseBody and body ErrResponseBody(errorType=Auth failed, errorDetail=Email or password is wrong)
2024-08-16 08:56:00.726 [eventLoopGroupProxy-7-1] INFO  ktor.application -- Received call: POST /api/user-service/login -> 406 Not Acceptable



What do you mean by the Auth guard? Can you share a complete code snippet where the HttpException is thrown?

@AlekseiTirman its not smth complexed, just a function, which tries to get session_token cookie and search it in redis. If failed, throw HttpException

I mean, where is this code located? I cannot reproduce the problem when an exception is thrown in a route handler.

@AlekseiTirman added

Can you share the server logs? I've created a gist (https://gist.github.com/Stexxe/e9b65f754a4ede4c2dfeb2d2fff7470d) with simplified code for your issue, but I can't reproduce it. Can you modify it to make the problem reproducible?

@AlekseiTirman, well... just tried to come up with smth. But i struggle to reproduce it, even in my app it occurs only at several http-post handlers, which seem to be same as others. Perhaps im not competent enough to report this
Serializing json by hands solves the issue tho
Attached logs, but they seem not usefull

You should enable the TRACE level logging.

@AlekseiTirman done. Here is the issue i guess No suitable content converter found for response type class _4Tipsy.TinyCloudAPI.AppKt$mainModule$ErrResponseBody and body ErrResponseBody(errorType=Auth failed, errorDetail=Email or password is wrong)

Can you share the definition of the _4Tipsy.TinyCloudAPI.AppKt$mainModule$ErrResponseBody class?

@AlekseiTirman its already in question. Little data class in App.kt

The class looks fine. It would be great if you could prepare a reproducer.
